# Error in starting Hyperledger fabcar sample application

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to run fab car sample application from http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/write_first_app.html

when **./startFabric.sh node** trying to create channel with below command

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
```

It gives error as

> flag provided but not defined: -e

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is the issue with the docker version.After upgrading docker it work.

Answer (score 0):

The Fabric samples require Docker 17.06.2-ce or later